# rollup treeshaking doesn't work if any unused function has external dependency

Tags: rollup, styled-components, tree-shaking

// file1.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const myDiv = styled.div``;

export const myLabel = styled.label``;
```

// input.js --> Rollup input file to bundle

```
import {myDiv} from "./file1"

export {myDiv};
```

Ideally myLabel should not be bundled as its not imported as per treeshaking. But bundle includes both myDiv and myLabel.

Please help me with understanding.

Comment: There might not be enough detail here to get a quality answer.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss updated the question. My bad

Comment: See this issue. https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1195

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings Thanks. Even I have create an issue there - https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1829

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the issue by adding { modules: false } on the babel loader preset

```
{ 
 loader: 'babel-loader',
 options: {
  presets: [ ["@babel/preset-env", { modules: false }] ],
 } 
}
```